# Is it possible to define a ng-template inside typescript file?

Tags: angular

normally we define `ng-template` inside HTML and then ViewQuery it if its needed inside the component class.

```
<ng-template #myNormalTemplate>
  <span> hehe </span>
</ng-template>
```

but is it possible somehow to define a `ng-template` inside a ts-file?

like so ? (pseudocode, and yes I know its an abstract class)

```
const myNormalTemplate = new TemplateRef<any>('<span> hehe </span>');
```

Comment: Nope. However you could create small component and use `*ngComponentOutlet` for example